# Would IRC Be a Good Medium for Game App Communication

Tags: game-engine, communication, irc

If I were to create a mobile game, such as Go Fish, where a number of users could play, I need an easy way for all the apps to communicate.  I don't want a user to need a google or other account to register.

I thought that IRC could be used.  I realize I'd have to have a way of getting the clients to know about each other for a particular game, but would IRC be ok?  Is that against the TOS?  Is it an appropriate use of the service?

I want an easy, always-free way for apps to communicate with each other.  Low volume messages, fairly quick response time.  Completely anonymous.

Answer (score -1):

IRC is just a simple protocol and games have been using it for chat for decades.

Its probably not ideal for a modern game though, particularly because it poorly handles users losing connection.

You also have to host the server as its not peer-to-peer or anything so it requires maintenance and isn't entirely free. You'd probably also need to customize the server for your needs anyway so requires further work.

That all said I'm not super familiar with alternatives in the space.